# Best practices for GeoDjango Models

Tags: django, geodjango

I have a classic GeoDjango model

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
  vessel    = models.ForeignKey(Vessel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
  point     = models.PointField()
```

However usage seems quite clumsy;

```
>>> foo = somevessel.location_set.create(point=Point(5, 23))
>>> foo.point.x
5.0
```

I still want to store the location as a point but would prefer to interact with the model with more native looking code, something like

```
>>> foo = somevessel.location_set.create(latitude=5, longitude=12)
>>> foo.latitude
5.0
```

Is this against best practices? And is there a simple way to achieve this in Django?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that implicitly formalizing your point like this, i.e. with latitude and longitude [FloatField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FloatField)s, will not allow you to fully benefit from [spatial lookup capabilities](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/). If not a "bad practice", this is likely to be a no-starter.

> I still want to store the location as a point but would prefer to interact with the model with more native looking code,

To interact with the model in a more native looking way, I would define properties in my model class which would actually return latitude and/or longitude, doing

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
  vessel    = models.ForeignKey(Vessel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
  point     = models.PointField()

  @property
  def latitude(self):
      return self.point.x

  @property
  def longitude(self):
      return self.point.y
```

Allowing you to do

```
>>> foo = somevessel.location_set.create(point=Point(5, 23))
>>> foo.latitude
5.0
```